# jQuery smooth scrolling script doesn't work on dropdown links

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a one-page design and I'm having trouble implementing the smooth scrolling script.

The script works on simple links, even on a menu item without dropdown.

I've tried modifying the script a little bit or even tried a different one, but still the same problem.

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#section-2" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> WER WIR SIND </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.domain.de">TEAM</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www..domain.de">PARTNER</a>

    </div>
</li>
```

If there's a normal link, it works, if it has the dropdown-toggle class it doesn't work.

Example of working link:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#section-7" class="nav-link"> KONTAKT  </a>
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when you click on a dropdown link?

Comment: On hover, it will reveal the dropdown-menu (current behaviour).
On click, it should scroll to a section that has an ID